# Possible ways to form a series of length n which has only two letters(A,B), A should exist at least two times more than B at any index.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

If a series contains only letters A and B.
How to find possible no.of arrangements in such a way that
A appears at least twice the times B at any point of an arrangement.

Ex:
For array of size : `4` the possible `3` combinations are.

```
AABA
AAAB
AAAA
```

For array of size : `5` the possible `4` combinations are.

```
AABAA
AAABA
AAAAB
AAAAA
```

How can we generalise this into a formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us first count the number of sequences which have $a$ instances of the letter "A" and $b$ instances of the letter "B," such that the numbers of A's is at least twice the number of B's in any initial segment. This is the weak variant of the generalization of Bertrand's ballot problem, and the number of valid sequences is known to be 
$$
\frac{a+1-2b}{a+1}\binom{a+b}a.
$$
For several proofs, see [*Four Proofs of the Ballot Theorem*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/252059419_Four_Proofs_of_the_Ballot_Theorem) by Marc Renault. For example, when $a=3$ and $b=1$, this is $\frac{3+1-2\cdot 1}{3+1}\binom{3+1}3=2$, corresponding to the sequences `AABA` and `AAAB`.

However, you just want to count sequences of a given length, $n$, with an arbitrary number of A's. Therefore, you should sum over all possible valid values of $a$, and the result is
$$
\boxed{\sum_{a=\lceil 2n/3\rceil}^n\frac{3a+1-2n}{a+1}\binom{n}{a}.}
$$
I do not know if this summation has a closed form.

Comment: Hi Mike, could you please explain the formula. what if A is at least K times of B at any instance of time. could we find at least 2 times and subtract at least k-1 times?.

Comment: @DharmendraParmar The paper I linked explains the formula in four ways, and generalizes to any $K$.